# How to find the column values present in a given sentence? mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider the following mysql table

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          Mike
3          Paul
4          John
```

And consider the input sentence

```
Mark and Paul are very good friends since 2000.
```

Expected output

```
Mark , Paul
```

I want to find the names present in the input sentence.
Does mysql provides any options to find this. Or any ideas?

Comment: This isn't the kind of thing that SQL is terribly good at, so despite the apparent overhead, I'd be tempted to find a solution in application level code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved two way. Using 'IN' and 'REGEX' operator of mysql.

**By using 'IN' Operator**

```
<?php

$string = "Mark and Paul are very good friends since 2000.";
$sql_in = "'".implode("','",explode(" ",$string))."'";

//Will return all the records for which name match with any word in given sentence.
$mysql_query = "select * from table_name where name in($sql_in)";

?>
```

**By using 'REGEX'**

```
<?php

$string = "Mark and Paul are very good friends since 2000.";
$regex_string = str_replace(' ','|',$string);

//Will return all the records for which name match with any word in given sentence.
$mysql_query = "select * from table_name where name REGEX '^(".$regex_string.")'";

?>
```

Comment: Ok thats a good idea. Is this the only way i can solve this problem? Beacuse this query is little bit costly, may take long time to execute.

Comment: I think you should do it using REGEX but not sure.

Comment: Ok. Lets see ideas from other people too.

Comment: @jdoe Please check my  updaed answer. I have share two ways to achieve your requirement. Another way is REGEX.

Comment: Why you guys down vote without mentioning the reason behind it? What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that mysql have some options for that. But you can split the string and search for the names.

```
$sentence = "Mark and Paul are very good friends since 2000."

//some code to get all names from the database
//simulation mysql-output as array
$names = array("Mark", "Mike", "Paul", "John");

//first split the String into a array what contains all words of the sentences
$array = explode(" ", $sentence);

//now you can check if any words in the array eqauls a name in your database
//create a foreach loop to check all words
foreach($array as $word) {

    //search if the word contains in the array
    if(in_array($word, $names)) {
        //this word is a searched name
        print_r("Word ".$word." is a name!\n");
    }
    else {
        //this word isn't a name
    }
}
```

In the If/Else you can code a custum handler. Notice if the sentence ends with a dot that the last word have at the last char a dot(.). You can check it and remove the dot with the `substr` function.

I don't test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try stored procedure. I have tested this query for random paragraph and get following execution time with three option

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE FindInDB
    @INSTR varchar(255) 
 AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SEPERATOR as VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @SP INT
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @SEPERATOR = ' '

    -- Create Temporary table add all words in it 
    CREATE TABLE #tempTab (name varchar(50) not null)
    WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @SEPERATOR + '%', @INSTR ) <> 0 

    BEGIN
      SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%' + @SEPERATOR + '%',@INSTR)
      SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
      SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
      INSERT INTO #tempTab (name) VALUES (@VALUE)
    END

  -- Total execution time   15      0       7.5000

 --SELECT [Name]
 --FROM [tblName] 
 --where Name  IN (SELECT name FROM #tempTab)

 --Total execution time 15      15      0       10.0000

 --SELECT distinct [tblName].[Name]
 --FROM [tblName] 
 --inner join #tempTab on #tempTab.name = tblName.Name;

 --Total execution time 15      15      15      15      0       12.0000

 SELECT [Name]
 FROM [tblName] 
 where EXISTS (SELECT name FROM #tempTab 
 where #tempTab.name = tblName.Name )

 DROP TABLE #tempTab
 END
 GO
```